# How to default select user in People Picker?

Tags: spfx, spfx-webparts, people-picker

I want to set default selected user on people picker?

```
<NormalPeoplePicker
                onChange={this._onChange.bind(this)}
                onResolveSuggestions={this._onFilterChanged}
                getTextFromItem={(persona: IPersonaProps) => persona.primaryText}
                pickerSuggestionsProps={suggestionProps}
                className={'ms-PeoplePicker'}
                key={'normal'}
                itemLimit={1}
                defaultSelectedItems={()}


              />
```

How to use defaultSelectedItems?
Thanks

Comment: You mean the current logged in user should be set as default in a people picker?

Comment: yes, the loged user should be set as default

Comment: I have added the code below in answers. 
Please don't forget to upvote and mark the answer as accepted in case it helped you!

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this using REST API:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

var userid = _spPageContextInfo.userId;

function GetUserLogin() {
var requestUri = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/getuserbyid(" + userid + ")";

var requestHeaders = { "accept" : "application/json;odata=verbose" };

$.ajax({
  url : requestUri,
  contentType : "application/json;odata=verbose",
  headers : requestHeaders,
  success : QuerySuccess,
  error : QueryError
});
}

function QuerySuccess(data, request){
  //removes the claims encoding
  var loginName = data.d.LoginName.split('|')[1];
  $("div[title='PeoplePickerColumnName']").val(loginName);
}

function QueryError(error) {
  alert(error);
}

GetUserLogin();

});
```

[Reference](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/105130/set-default-value-in-people-picker-javascript-jquery)