# Invalid ViewState when Filling PeoplePicker using jQuery

Tags: jquery, error, people-picker

On my `NewForm.aspx` or `EditForm.aspx` pages [I am using jQuery](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/105130/set-default-value-in-people-picker-javascript-jquery/123295?noredirect=1#comment169544_123295) to fill in a peoplepicker control.

The problem is that this causes the page to POST this error:

```
"This Page has been modified since you opened it. You must open the page again."
```

This error, in the ULS is `System.Web.UI.ViewStateException: Invalid viewstate`.

[This page has a few suggestions](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/tom/archive/2008/03/14/validation-of-viewstate-mac-failed-error.aspx) to solve this, but I haven't figured out just what to do yet.  Also, [I have a thread in the spservices Discussions](https://spservices.codeplex.com/discussions/648386) over on CodePlex, but I need an answer.  [And there is this thread](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/45224/this-page-has-been-modified-since-you-opened-it-you-must-open-the-page-again-r), but it's tagged `C#` and doesn't help me with a jQuery issue.

Here is the code I'm using to fill in the peoplepicker control:

```
SetPeoplePickerToCurrentUser("Requestor",false);

function SetPeoplePickerToCurrentUser(whatDisplayName, overwrite){
    //var currentControlValue = $().SPServices.SPFindPeoplePicker({  peoplePickerDisplayName: whatDisplayName }).row.find("span[class='ms-entity-resolved']").attr("title");    
    var currentControlValue = $("div[title='People Picker']").text().trim();
    if(overwrite || currentControlValue == undefined || currentControlValue == ""){ 
        var currentuser = $().SPServices.SPGetCurrentUser({ fieldName: "Name", debug: false });
        var peoplepicker = $("div[title='People Picker']");
        peoplepicker.text(currentuser); 
        $('a[title="Check Names"]').click();        
     }
}
```

**[update]**

Well, I've discovered that this actually does work, but if the user refreshes the page without saving, THEN it locks up with the viewstate error.  Normally, a person can refresh without saving.  The function won't modify the value again if there is anything in it.  Normally, if a person refreshes a page without saving, a people-picker control gets blanked out, but the custom form's people-picker does not get emptied out.

Comment: It seems to me that what you have should work, provided it is properly set up. Try this to troubleshoot: remove all your code from the form except for the jQuery reference. Then execute the two lines of JS in your browser console, one at a time, just to see if it does what you expect it to. If it does, then there's an issue with the way you've wired it up. In any case I suspect there is something else going on with this form, because it has no business throwing that invalid viewstate error.

Comment: I updated my question with some more details as well as a bounty.

Comment: The invalid viewstate error is thrown server-side unless I'm mistaken, and the JavaScript would have no effect on it whatsoever. I suspect that whatever is going on has nothing to do with this code.

Comment: I disagree.  The invalid viewstate ONLY happens when I try to set the value in the peoplepicker.  Maybe its not the code directly, but it *is* the code indirectly.  If I don't try to set the value via javascript I never see the error.

Comment: Get rid of the SPServices calls and it will work.  You don't need them.  Get the current user from the "Welcome" text on the page, instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get rid of the SPServices calls and it will work. You don't need them. Get the current user from the "Welcome" text on the page, instead.

```
// Default the Requestor's Name
var welcomeText = $('[id*="zz8_Menu"]').text(); // this is zz7_Menu in SP 2007
var user = welcomeText.split('Welcome ')[1];
var counter=0;
$('div[title="People Picker"]').each(function() {
    //alert(counter);
    if (counter == 1) { // this is because I was setting the 2nd people picker on the page
        $(this).html(user);  // <-- this is the magic
    }
    counter++;
    $('a[title="Check Names"]').click();  // <-- clicks the "Check Name" button programmatically to resolve your user
});
```

Comment: I think you are right; it was the `spservices` call fetching the username that must have been invalidating the page.  I replaced it with your function and it worked.  Nota Bene, though, for 2010, I fetched the `user` value with this instead: `$('[id*="zz17_Menu"] span').text();` and didn't have to use `split` on `welcomeText`.  But it worked! I am astounded.   But you can also fetch the username without spservices like this: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/a/53516/7452

Comment: Yeah, they've modified that ID to be different in all the SP versions, I stopped keeping up with them.  Glad you found the right ID.  In 2013, they stopped putting "Welcome" beside the logged-in user's name.

Comment: I since found out, you could do the SPServices call, but they don't have "Name" as a field - there is "FirstName" and "LastName", and you'd have to do some concatenation: `var thisUsersValues = $().SPServices.SPGetCurrentUser({
 fieldNames: ["FirstName", "LastName"],
 debug: false
}); var name = thisUsersValues.FirstName + ' ' + thisUsersValues.LastName;`  Then you would still use `.html(name)` to add it in.